# Python socket.py gaierror when trying to use Google Maps API

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using socket.py's create_connection method to connect to Google Maps API, I think the way I'm using it is giving me an error. When I try this with a host such as www.python.org everything works fine. What's the issue that I can't understand.

```
>>> socket.create_connection(("www.maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=L5R2W9&key=******", 443))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `socket` module is too low-level for making the type of HTTP requests you are thinking. If you really want to make a socket connection to `www.googleapis.com`, try this instead:

```
socket.create_connection(("www.maps.googleapis.com", 443))
```

If you want to make an actual HTTP request, you can try the `requests` module instead:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=L5R2W9&key=******")
```

Comment: hmm, ok I'll try out your first suggestion. requests uses urllib3 which uses socket and calls that method. I have my own simple http library I am making which fails on that call but requests does not. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: If you identified the point where `urllib3` calls `socket.create_connection`, you could insert the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the call to set a breakpoint and then inspect the actual value passed. That line might come in handy while troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks I'll try that out too, your first suggestion gets rid of the error and allows me to send requests to the socket via httplib.